# FontForge scripting “Insert Text Outlines…” dialog

Tags: font-design, font-forge

I'm a Python developer dabbling in font creation for the first time as a side hobby using FontForge 2017-07-31 over XQuartz 2.7.11 on MacOS 10.12.6

My goal is to create a series of novelty font, in which the glyph for each letter of the alphabet will be replaced by the outline of an entire word, eg:

- "A as in aye"
- "B as in bee"
- "C as in cite"
- "D as in djinn"
- "E as in eye"
- ...etc...

I have no problem create a handful of glyphs manually in the FontForge UI via following steps (see images below):

1. in Drawing Tool delete all points from original glyph
2. use Pen Tool to create a horizontal line
3. Element > Insert Text Outline...
4. type in alternate word (eg "AYE") > Insert
5. repeat for all glyphs

But given the number of words/fonts I want to create, I'd like to automate the "Insert Text Outline..." UI dialogue using FontForge scripting capability. But I don't see any corresponding methods under the scripting docs

Anyone know how I can do this? I'm open to paying for a commercial app if necessary but of course free is preferable

Thanks!

PS: the folks on [Meta suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300321/site-recommendation-for-fontforge-scripting/300323#300323) I use this forum for this question, lemme know if otherwise

EDIT: this project also needs CJK support

EDIT2: adding images clarifying what I'm trying to do

**Step 3**
[image: Step 3]

**Step 4**
[image: Step 4]

**Step 5**
[image: Step 5]

Comment: How exactly will substituting a word for the letter work with CJK, where each ‘letter’ is essentially a word(-ish entity)?

Comment: I'm actually going to suggest you ask somewhere else to get any useful replies. Python programming of Fontforge is probably a bit beyond most graphic designers. Maybe the fontforge users mailing list? https://sourceforge.net/p/fontforge/mailman/fontforge-users/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is worth looking at, but apparently if you have Illustrator or Photoshop, there's a plugin for creating Open Type fonts directly in those applications: https://www.fontself.com/

Blurb from the website:

> Fontself Maker is an add-on for Photoshop & Illustrator CC that brings
>   you font creation superpowers.
>
> Enjoy a new skill in your next graphic / web / mobile / print / icon /
>   UI / UX projects!
>
> Create fonts in seconds  (just drag & drop)

I can't vouch for it as I've never tried it, and I have no connection with that site or the developers.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately FontSelf doesn't support CJK, which is one of my requirements (have edited original post to note this point)